# Sharing Images on Android M with Facebook Messenger SDK

Tags: facebook

If you try to use Messenger SDK on Android M, the image sharing fails saying "Messenger can't process this file" 
Always happens!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here, its all about the permissions. The issue is that , if Messenger doesn't have the storage permission, the Messenger doesn't ask for it when you try to share via the SDK. Once the user does grant the permission, everything works. as a side note, you can't ask for the permission on behalf of Messenger. 
I wrote up a bug, and turns out the Messenger is aware of it. the bug can be found here:https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/197924700540706/